# Regex to modify SQL-Dump

Tags: regex

I have an SQL-File which i need to modify before importing it into the database.

```
INSERT INTO 'content' ('id', 'title', 'alias', 'title_alias', ... ) VALUES
(1, ... , ... , ... )
(2, ... , ... , ... )
(3, ... , ... , ... )
```

Now i want to kick one of the columns, assume `alias` (the third value)

What would be the appropriate regex for notepad++? I didn't get measly tries to work:-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with regex, but why don't you do it the other way? I mean:

1. create the table as necessary
2. load the data
3. delete the unneeded column:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name;
   ```

Comment: I migrate data from a given db to another already existing db with slightly different model. Thats why i want to modify the sql, else i needed to work with temporary tables, that would be an idea...